# Event handling and Observer pattern (GoF)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, event-handling, observer-pattern

These days, I am learning Gof design patterns in C#  and I think event-handling might have something to do with Observer pattern. My question is while solving problems with events and their handlers, why we still need observer pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is comparing apples and pears.

The observer pattern is a solution to a problem. It doesn't tell you how to implement the solution, but is more like a blue print.

Thus, the event model in .NET is an implementation of the observer pattern. The `EventHandler` delegate is defining the observer and the `event` keyword takes care of dealing with all notifications in the subject, just as defined in the observer pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much